# greenmail server not receiving the mail

Tags: java, testing, junit, greenmail

- My Unit Test for  class for email through Greenmail

  public class GreenMailTest {

  ```
  private GreenMail greenMail;
  private EmailServiceImpl emailService = new EmailServiceImpl();

  private MessageTemplateService messageTemplateService;

  private EmailProperties emailProperties;

  private Properties props;

   private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "abcdef123";
      private static final String USER_NAME = "hascode";
      private static final String EMAIL_USER_ADDRESS = "hascode@localhost";
      private static final String EMAIL_TO = "someone@localhost.com";
      private static final String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Test E-Mail";
      private static final String EMAIL_TEXT = "This is a test e-mail.";
      private static final String LOCALHOST = "localhost";
     // private GreenMail mailServer;


  @Before
  public void testSmtpInit() {
      //ServerSetup setup = new ServerSetup();
      greenMail = new GreenMail(ServerSetupTest.SMTP);
      greenMail.start();
      messageTemplateService = mock(MessageTemplateService.class);
      emailProperties = mock(EmailProperties.class);
      emailService.setEmailProperties(emailProperties);
  }

  @Test
  public void testEmail() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

      greenMail.setUser(EMAIL_USER_ADDRESS, USER_NAME, USER_PASSWORD);

          // create the javax.mail stack with session, message and transport ..
          Properties props = System.getProperties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", LOCALHOST);
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", ServerSetupTest.SMTP.getPort());
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
          Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
          try {
              msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_TO));
               msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                          InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_USER_ADDRESS, false));
                          msg.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT);
                          msg.setText(EMAIL_TEXT);
                          msg.setSentDate(new Date());
                          Transport t =  session.getTransport("smtp");
                          t.connect(EMAIL_USER_ADDRESS, USER_PASSWORD);
                          t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                         // assertEquals("250 OK\n", t.getLastServerResponse());
                          t.close();
          } catch (MessagingException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
          }





      // fetch messages from server
      MimeMessage[] messages = greenMail.getReceivedMessages();
  ```
- I used this code to test the email server on junit.
- But the server does not return any message
- what i did wrong.
- I change the code please review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GreenMail is running at localhost. Adjust your smtp host accordingly:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
```

---

**Edit**

To summarize the large number of comments: The additional problem came from fact that `mock-javamail` was on the classpath.

Comment: props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost"); how to change this to specific host.